# UILabel with trailing spaces doesn't center properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a string that is a random sequence of numbers including spaces

```
NSString *myString;
```

I print that to a label

```
_myLabel.text = myString;
```

I wanted it to be centered, so I use

```
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

But it doesn't work properly. When centering, it ignore any trailing zeros. But the trailing zeros are characters too! Can I make it recognize them?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a more detailed code sample or a screenshot?  Is the text being cut off?  If so you may just need to call sizeToFit on the label after setting the text.

Comment: The label size is set manually, and is big enough. The number of characters is fixed. The problem arises only when the last character is a space. So if I have myString = @"Hello     ", I end up with the word 'Hello' centered, whereas I would expect it to end at the center due to the 5 spaces (and the monospaced font I've used).

Comment: Try replacing the standard space characters with non-break spaces.

Comment: Looks like UILabel isn't allowing us to turn off the trimming but I'm curious as to why you would need to allow this to remain.  Maybe if you explain the use case we can find a better solution to the problem rather than trying to keep trailing whitespace.

Comment: I have a few lines and need them to be aligned with each other.

Comment: @Steve  -it's very obvious when using **monospace fonts**

Answer (score 4):

The way text works on label is - it is formatted by standard formatting information - like trimming etc. If you don't want ios to take control on that. You can programmatically set attributedText. this does not go thru formatting. Here is apple's documentation on that

---

> `attributedText` The styled text displayed by the label.
>
> `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property is `nil` by default. Assigning a new value to
>   this property also replaces the value of the text property with the
>   same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In
>   addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the `font`,
>   `textColor`, and other style-related properties so that they reflect the
>   style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.